# Android Studio (IntelliJ) Syntax Highlighting Not Working In One Class

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

My problem is that the syntax highlighting in one class just stops after I run my app. Even when I restart Android Studio everything is still white except the Java keywords. Deleting the class and creating a new one and pasting it in there doesnt help either. Very strange in my opinion. But in the other classes the highlighting still works. I've already reinstalled Android Studio and restored the settings to default. Nothing helped. I hope you can help me.

[image: First Image]

---

[image: Second Image]

The first picture shows the class where the highlighting is not working. The second picture is another class but there the highlighting works fine.

Comment: The first Picture is an anonymous function not a class. maybe it is because of that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But I should have mentioned that the image is only a part of the class and not the complete class. Im sorry for that. Anyways I found the solution. I was stupid an selected "Highlighting: None" At the bottom right. But when I select "Highlighting: Syntax" It works.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is a bit late, but it may help someone in the future.

- copy all the code of this file
- delete the file
- recreate the file
- paste all the code again
- done

For me it always works