# Failed to instantiate one or more classes

Tags: android

The following classes could not be instantiated:

> com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout (Open
>   Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in
>   your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the
>   IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the
>   project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details
>   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Theme_Delegate.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources_Theme_Delegate.java:74)
>     at
>   android.content.res.Resources$Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(Resources.java:1520)
>     at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:751)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.resources.TextAppearance.(TextAppearance.java:75)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.internal.CollapsingTextHelper.setExpandedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:309)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout.(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:212)
>     at
>   com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout.(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:151)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1097)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:501) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

I am getting this warning while using `com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: Have you imported the material gradle file?  `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

Comment: You can find the answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61545141/android-studio-intellij-syntax-highlighting-not-working-in-one-class/73825099#73825099) @gallosalocin

Answer (score -1):

Sync your project after adding the dependency

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Try to Build Project(Gradle Build) if you added material design dependency i.e

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

in the build.gradle(app level) file already and then refresh the Layout.